# Informatica equelent column comparision in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Looking for some help to implement the similar logic which is in informatica.

We need to compare some columns in a dataframe to check is there any change in the record(I have to compare around 60 columns out 80 columns in the record) - If we see some difference in the columns, that means its a changed record. Otherwise no change in the record.

We are using Spark and scala for the development and really appreciate if any insights on this.

Thanks,
Vee

Comment: you can use except function for that. if you need more details you would need to update your question with what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have dataframe  and comparing each column(This  dataframe contains single record with new date and old data(colums start with old_). val DF = DF1.filter((DF1("Id").isNotNull && DF1("old_Id").isNotNull) &&
        (DF1("old_col1").equals(DF1("col1"))) &&
        (DF1("old_col2").equals(DF1("col2")))

Comment: You should update the question Bab, with the sample data for both dataframes and your tried codes and expected outputs.